# Studio Error: "Graph connection has not been made"

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise-graph

I've set up a 3-node DSE cluster with Studio using Docker compose.

I've added the command switches/options -g and -s

The server starts with the following log message:

```
Applying changes to /opt/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml ...
done.
Applying changes to /opt/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra-rackdc.properties ...
done.
Running dse cassandra -f -R -k -g -s
getopt: invalid option -- ' '
getopt: invalid option -- '-'
getopt: invalid option -- ' '
getopt: invalid option -- '-'
Tomcat: Logging to /opt/dse/tomcat
```

When I start Studio and load the "DataStax Graph QuickStart v6.8.0" notebook, I get the error "This notebook uses graph 'food_qs', but a Graph connection has not been made.

NOTE: Yes, I have created and tested the connection - and verified the CQL from Studio is working.

Here is my docker-compose yaml file:

```
version: '3'

# see: https://docs.datastax.com/en/docker/docs/managing/recommended-settings.html

# NOTE: his docker-compose file is for a 3-node cluster with DSE Studio. It's recourses are limited to ensure
# this cluster can run simultaneously with other clusters on the same host (i.e. Cluouders, Postgres, MongoDB, etc.)
# If you want more performance from the Cassandra cluster, you can increase the resources for each node.

services:

  DSE-N1:
    image: datastax/dse-server:6.8.16-ubi7
    command: ['-k', '-g', '-s']
    container_name: DSE-N1
    hostname: DSE-N1
    # use static ip address
    networks:
     dc1ring:
      ipv4_address: 172.30.0.2
    ports:
      - 9042:9042
      - 8182:8182
      - 9077:9077
    # Maps cassandra exercises to a local folder.
    # This preserves data across container restarts.
    volumes:
      # you will need to chmod these folders to 777
      - ./dse-n1:/var/lib/cassandra # see: https://docs.datastax.com/en/docker/docs/managing/mount-data-volumes.html
      - ./dse-shared:/home/shared
    environment:
      - DS_LICENSE=accept
      - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=1500M
      - SEEDS=DSE-N1, DSE-N2, DSE-N3
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
    restart: always   

  DSE-N2:
    image: datastax/dse-server:6.8.16-ubi7
    command: ['-k', '-g', '-s']
    container_name: DSE-N2
    hostname: DSE-N2
    networks:
        dc1ring:
            ipv4_address: 172.30.0.3
    ports:
      - 9043:9042
      - 8183:8182
      - 9078:9077
    volumes:
      # you will need to chmod these folders to 777
      - ./dse-n2:/var/lib/cassandra # see: https://docs.datastax.com/en/docker/docs/managing/mount-data-volumes.html
      - ./dse-shared:/home/shared
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    ulimits:
      memlock: -1
    environment:
      - DS_LICENSE=accept
      - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=1500M
      - SEEDS=DSE-N1, DSE-N2, DSE-N3
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
    restart: always 

  DSE-N3:
    image: datastax/dse-server:6.8.16-ubi7
    command: ['-k', '-g', '-s']
    container_name: DSE-N3
    hostname: DSE-N3
    networks:
      dc1ring:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.0.4
    ports:
      - 9044:9042
      - 8184:8182
      - 9079:9077
    volumes:
      # you will need to chmod these folders to 777
      - ./dse-n3:/var/lib/cassandra # see: https://docs.datastax.com/en/docker/docs/managing/mount-data-volumes.html
      - ./dse-shared:/home/shared
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    ulimits:
      memlock: -1
    environment:
      - DS_LICENSE=accept
      - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=1500M
      - SEEDS=DSE-N1, DSE-N2, DSE-N3
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
    restart: always 
 
  DSE-STUDIO:
    image: datastax/dse-studio:latest
    container_name: DSE-STUDIO
    hostname: DSE-STUDIO
    networks:
      dc1ring:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.0.5
    ports:
      # The Web UI exposed to our host
      - "9091:9091"
    volumes:
      - ./dse-studio:/var/lib/datastax-studio
      - ./dse-shared:/home/shared
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    ulimits:
      memlock: -1
    environment:
      - DS_LICENSE=accept
    restart: always
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 3G

networks:
    dc1ring:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.30.0.0/16

volumes:
  dse-n1:
  dse-n2:
  dse-n3:
  dse-studio:
```